# Launch a URL obtained as string from JSON

Tags: android, json, url, onclicklistener

I am obtaining a JSON Array from a website with title and URL.
I am able to display title  as a list but what I want to then do is have the list displayed as
- LIST1          >
- LIST2          >
- LIST3          >

List are title of webpages with corresponding webpage url.

I want to launch these url when the user clicks these list.

Problem :
1) I cant display  > on my list

2) I don't know how to use the obtained URL to be able to launch that using the onclicklistener()

Here is the JSON array:

[{"title":"I am bad - a poem ","date":"10/05/2013","url":"http://www.abcd.co.uk/projects-by-country/middle-east/555-i-am-bad-a-poem"},{"title":"He is bad - a story","date":"09/05/2013","url":"http://www.abcd.co.uk/projects-by-country/middle-east/554-he-is-bad-a-story"}]

Comment: better to post the JSON array for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Save your title and URL in a HashMap.
- Pass the HashMap to the ListView Adapter class.
- you could have two TextView's in the list Item's layout. one for title and another for URL.
- set the url's textView Visibility to View.GONE if you don't want to display.
- onClick of the ListItem write the following code:

  ```
  myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

     TextView urltv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url_tv);          
     String url = urltv.getText().toString();
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
     startActivity(intent);

    }

  });
  ```

Comment: There are various other solutions as well. You could also make the HashMap accessible to all methods and use the Title(key of hashmap) to get the URL(Value).

Comment: can you please provide some example of the above idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16731023/2386166   - Do I have to write the code to use this intent to be able to launch the website?

Comment: if you write the above code in the answer, the Android OS will give the user an option to choose from a list of apps which can handle URL data. possibly list of browsers installed in the device. on ListItem click it will open the web url.